# Vulkan offscreen renderer question regarding an example code from Sacha Willems

Tags: c++, graphics, vulkan

Can someone explain how Sascha Willem's offscreen example works?

In his [offscreen example](https://github.com/SaschaWillems/Vulkan/tree/master/examples/offscreen) it looks like the scene is SUPPOSED to be first rendered onto an offscreen framebuffer and then added onto the second render.
However I can't quite see how this happens, in the [command buffer building code](https://github.com/SaschaWillems/Vulkan/blob/master/examples/offscreen/offscreen.cpp#L305) I don't see how the offscreen framebuffer ends up being presented.

In a different example [raytracingbasic](https://github.com/SaschaWillems/Vulkan/blob/master/examples/raytracingbasic/raytracingbasic.cpp#L775-L801) I see the following code which I feel is easier to understand (I believe here the ray traced image simply gets copied onto the swapchain presentation image, thereby allowing for presentation onto the screen)

```
vkCmdCopyImage(drawCmdBuffers[i], storageImage.image, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_SRC_OPTIMAL, swapChain.images[i], VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL, 1, &copyRegion);
```

Comment: "*I don't see how the offscreen framebuffer ends up being presented.*" If it's "offscreen", then it *doesn't* get presented. That's what it means to call it an "offscreen framebuffer".

Comment: I get that it doesn't get presented directly, but I don't understand how the example makes the contents of offscreen framebuffer impact the final presentation image.

Comment: From the documentation i found "Basic offscreen rendering in two passes. First pass renders the mirrored scene to a separate framebuffer with color and depth attachments, second pass **samples** from that color attachment for rendering a mirror surface."
I can't figure out where the "sampling" is specificied in the code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no presentation of the offscreen image. The offscreen image is displayed in the second render pass by drawing a mirror plane that samples from the offscreen image.

Copying the image like in the ray tracing sample you mentioned is not possible in that case, sine the mirror plane is a 3D object and not a full screen triangle that never changes size or orientation.

This is done by setting up a combined image sampler descriptor from the offscreen image in `setupDescriptorSet`:

```cpp
std::vector<VkWriteDescriptorSet> writeDescriptorSets =
{
    // Binding 0 : Vertex shader uniform buffer
    vks::initializers::writeDescriptorSet(
        descriptorSets.mirror,
        VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_UNIFORM_BUFFER,
        0,
        &uniformBuffers.vsMirror.descriptor),
    // Binding 1 : Fragment shader texture sampler
    vks::initializers::writeDescriptorSet(
        descriptorSets.mirror,
        VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_COMBINED_IMAGE_SAMPLER,
        1,
        &offscreenPass.descriptor),
};
```

The sampling itself is then done in the fragment shader (`mirror.frag`):

```c
layout (binding = 1) uniform sampler2D samplerColor;
...
    if (gl_FrontFacing) 
    {
        // Only render mirrored scene on front facing (upper) side of mirror surface
        vec4 reflection = vec4(0.0);
        for (int x = -3; x <= 3; x++)
        {
            for (int y = -3; y <= 3; y++)
            {
                reflection += texture(samplerColor, vec2(projCoord.s + x * blurSize, projCoord.t + y * blurSize)) / 49.0;
            }
        }
        outFragColor += reflection;
    };
```